# ISO C forbids forward parameter declaration

Tags: c

When i try to compile this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void decoupeSecondes(int* pointeurHeures, int* pointeurMinutes, int* pointeurSecondes);

int main (void){
  int sec, min, heu;
  scanf("%d %d %d", &heu, &min, &sec);
  decoupeSecondes(&heu, &min, &sec);
  printf("%d heures, %d minutes et %d secondes",heu, min, sec);
  return 0;

}

void decoupeSecondes(int* pointeurHeures, int* pointeurMinutes, int* pointeurSecondes;){
*pointeurMinutes = *pointeurSecondes / 60;
*pointeurSecondes = *pointeurSecondes % 60;
*pointeurHeures = *pointeurMinutes/60;
*pointeurMinutes = *pointeurMinutes % 60;
}
```

I got this error: warning: ISO C forbids forward parameter declarations [-Wpedantic] and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extra semicolon

```
void decoupeSecondes(int* pointeurHeures, int* pointeurMinutes, int* pointeurSecondes;){
//      ...           ...                 ...               ...                 OOPS ^
```